# Getting " org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null keys not allowed" error when persist objects.

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I am using OpenJPA with Eclipse to persist object. I created a simple one to one unidirectional application. But it is giving Foreign key null error.

**Student Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Department department;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n\nID:" + id + "\nName:" + name + "\n\n" + department;
    }
}
```

**Department Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String deptName) {
        this.name = deptName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Department id: " + getId() + ", name: " + getName();
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="IBMJPADemo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <class>com.ibm.jpa.onetoone.model.Department</class>
        <class>com.ibm.jpa.onetoone.model.Student</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="root" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>           
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO"/>
            <!-- property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)" /-->
            <!-- property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults"
                value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict" /-->
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Client Program**

```
public class OneToOneClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("IBMJPADemo");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(2537);
        student.setName("K.Senthuran");

        Department dept = new Department();
        dept.setId(100);
        dept.setName("IT");
        student.setDepartment(dept);

        em.persist(student);

        em.flush();
        tx.commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

**Error**

Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null keys not allowed
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1817)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.flush(DelegatingBroker.java:1037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:652)
    at com.ibm.jpa.onetoone.client.OneToOneClient.main(OneToOneClient.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null keys not allowed
    at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractReferenceMap.put(AbstractReferenceMap.java:248)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ManagedCache.assignObjectId(ManagedCache.java:189)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assignObjectId(BrokerImpl.java:4949)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setStateManager(BrokerImpl.java:4046)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assertObjectIdAssigned(StateManagerImpl.java:636)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.afterFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1084)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1808)
    ... 3 more

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
K.Senthuran

Comment: Try to persist the `Department` first, and then `Student`. Since you are using `UniDirectional Mapping`, your Department should be persisted before persisting it with Student.

Comment: @RohitJain you might as well post it as the answer. Anyone answering would have to repeat what you said in the comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Kostja. Thats working fine. Please let me know it is must to persist two objects. When we use hibernate if we persist one object then otherone will be persisted by itself. For OpenJpa this may be the way to persist. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Uni-Directional` Mapping, so persisting your `Student` will not persist your `Department` too. So, you need to make sure that, while persisting the `Student`, the `Department` entity reference used is already persisted in the database, else you will get exception.

So, just persist the `department`, before you persist the `student`. I think that will solve your issue.

If you want that, persisting your `student` also persist the `department`, then you would need to use `bi-directional mapping`. i.e. Use a reference of `Student` in `Department`, with `@OneToOne` mapping, specifying a `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I tried the sample OneToOne unidirectional program and I persisted only one object. Otherone persisted by itself(Using EclipseLink). Please find the example from the bellow link.<br> http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToOneUnidirectional.htm. <br> Please let me know whether do we need to do any configuration changes in persistence.xml to support this functionality. Note: This problem only with OpenJPA. With otehr venders its working fine. I tried the bidirections onetoone relationship program also. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue.
First of all we have to mention the primary key attribute with @Id and @Column annotation. 
Then we have to add the following line in persistence.xml.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)" />
```

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)